# Can lack of grounding affect appliances?

Tags: grounding

Grounding is done because if charge leaks the external metal body of the appliance risking the life of anyone who touches it.

Does this charge leakage, of itself, affect the internal workings of an electrical or electronic appliance?

Could I be required to get an appliance repaired, because my house electrical network system lacked grounding?

Comment: GFCI circuits don't work without proper grounding.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams GFCIs will work without proper grounding. They operate by sensing the difference between Neutral current and Live current. The test button or an external tester will not work if no ground is connected as they can no longer simulate a fault to ground.

Comment: @RoyC: On your (east) side of the Atlantic RCDs (CFCIs) don't have an earth connection.  The test button connects a test resistor from one conductor *after* the sensing current transformer to the other conductor *before* the transformer. See the first diagram on [this page](https://www.jez.com.au/news-views-tips/circuit-protection/).

Comment: @RoyC yes and no. If there is no ground on the chassis there will be no earth leakage to flip the breaker till someone touches the thing with a ground connection through their feet. As such the appliance can be sitting very live. The GFI will, hopefully, trip when someone touches it, but there is no guarantee it wont kill them first.

Comment: @Trevor No the GFCI is designed to trip with a Live-Earth current low enough not to kill the person producing the current, otherwise  you might as well use a fuse.

Comment: @RoyC unfortunately there is a mechanical delay, it may be only a millisecond, but that's still enough to do serious harm to a susseptible individual. But regardless, it is still defeated till you touch the appliance.

Comment: @Trevor see https://www.nema.org/Products/Documents/NEMA-GFCI-2012-Field-Representative-Presentation.pdf

Comment: @RoyC again what about it.. That just tells you it needs to trip at that current, It does not say the current won't be amps during the 25mS  before it does. The latter is, unfortunately, not well understood by most.

Comment: @RoyC it's still better than a fuse though. With a 15A fuse, or breaker, you can have 14A going through you indefinitely and the fuse will never blow.

Comment: @Trevor at 240 V human body resistance is about 1 kOhms where are you getting all these Amps from?

Comment: @RoyC you are still missing the point, during the 25mS there is nothing to limit the current AT ALL.

Comment: @Trevor Do you understand Ohms's law? Live source to body resistance+Body Resistance (minimum 1k Ohms)+Body to floor resistance+Floor to Ground resistance. Apart from body resistance these tend to be at a minimum in wet areas where GFCIs are mandatory in an increasing number of jurisdictions can you tell me why this is if they don't work?

Comment: @RoyC after 40 years as an engineer I guess I do. You have to understand GFI's work to limit your exposure time, You have the full power of the mains available to you till the GFI opens.  How much actual current goes through you.. and your heart.. for that pulse depends on a number of variables, but the point is, NOTHING is limiting the current coming out of the appliance during the GFI's reaction time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have mentioned ESD, but I'd like to stress it again that static build up is very important to eliminate.

This is especially important for ANY appliance with a moving parts especially belts. You end up with a [Van-der-Graff Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) and can have thousands of volts build up on the chassis.

Also as [Ignacio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11606/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) mentioned, the lack of a ground on the chassis can mean the ground fault interrupter will not do it's job effectively as intended. Although ground fault interrupters do not actually monitor the ground line, if the chassis is isolated from ground and there is a short inside the unit, the chassis can become live and will remain so until someone touches it who IS grounded. At that point, hopefully, the ground fault interrupter will flip, but the intervening shock to the person touching it can still be lethal.

As to whether it affects the actual appliance. EMI and ESD can cause it to stop functioning, but other than that, it should work as normal provided there are no shorts or other faults inside. You did not mention the type of appliance though. If it is something that "connects" to something else, phone line, internet, audio/video source, the lack of a common ground can also be problematic.

Comment: What if it's TV

Comment: @Truth-seek hard to say, you may get some rather odd sound things happening.

Comment: Ah now I understand you are actually confusing two protection mechanisms. The case where a case is grounded and then is connected to live internally is protected for by a fuse or over current breaker. A low impedance short produces too much current for a GFCI I have seen a (bad) installation where only  a GFCI was used and it was destroyed by the over current, admittedly in that case it was a L-N short.

Answer (score 1):

Earth ground on appliances is used for shunting EMI noise and providing a safe connection between other earth grounded appliances and plumbing.  If not connected then each power supply and appliance may use up to 500uA of noise filter current and create a large voltage between earth and the missing earth connection.  (I*R)

Answer (score -3):

Grounding can help in the following ways.

1. It provides a safe leakage path for the internal charge due to motion, electron guns or induction. This protects a person from an electric shock which can be upto a mA when about a Kv can build up due to statics.

**2. It shields the circuits from external electric fields and provides some changing magnetic field shielding due to eddy currents. This helps for the repeatable functioning of the electronic circuits.**

3. It also helps when a wire dangles and touches the ground by protecting a person touching the shield.

**4. It also shields the internal circuit from the static charge carried by a person while touching the device.**

Points 2 and 4 show that the functioning of the circuit is protected by grounding.